# Confused on how to use mkdir with shellscript

Tags: linux, shell-script, mkdir

I'm trying to create a program that recursively makes folders for fun and I'm having trouble using mkdir. When running it in terminal it gives back these error messages:

> ./folder.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `mkdir'
> ./folder.sh: line 6: ' mkdir "folder$x"'

And my code is this:

```
5 for i in {1...1}
6   mkdir "folder$x"
7   $x = ($x + $1)
```

Comment: Also I had the loop at 1 for debugging.

Comment: Please do any googling before asking questions here because checking correct syntax of a popular loop command is trivial.

Comment: I Did try googling I couldn't find anything didn't work.

Comment: And you didn't find any of these https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/ https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-loops.php https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bash-scripting-for-loop/, all of which display the correct syntax...?

Comment: No I did not, and I did not know the loop was the issue since I did know it was reading "mkdir" as a syntax for the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a linux shell for loop should like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for item in {1..1}; do
    echo "folder${item}"
done
```

you lost `; do` and `done` part.

Comment: This works thanks for helping.

Comment: Glad this answer can help you, maybe you can try do deeper googling next time before ask this trivial type question. shell scripts has a long history like computer, questions like for loop, check if program is installed , replace string on file already have a lot tutorial. knowing how to use search engines is an important skill.

Comment: Well for whatever reason just about every article I found never included the "; do" and "done" for the loop, I also did not know what was the issue. But I really do appreciate your help.